# Difference between Feature Store and Datasets in Vertex AI GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

What is the difference between Feature Store and Dataset inside of Vertex AI (GCP)?
And why the Feature Store has Offline and Online serving nodes? What is it for?

Answer (score 0):

As described at the official documentation of [Vertex AI's Feature Store](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/featurestore/overview#benefits)
, a feature store is a container for organizing, storing, and serving ML feature. Basically its a more organized container that can be easily store or share features to permitted users. I would suggest reading the article linked above.

Online serving nodes is best described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/featurestore/managing-featurestores#onlineservingnodes):

"Online serving nodes provide the compute resources used to store and serve feature values for low-latency online serving."